# PLA Globbing up on the Extruder Nozzle

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, pla, extruder

My Ender 3 was printing great. However, I'm now getting all sorts of globbing up on the Extruder nozzle. This is causing the prints to fail, and if I come back after a print I'm often getting 1/3 of the print printed with gaps, etc before it totally fails. Any idea what is going on? Its the same roll of PLA that was printing fine at this temperature, etc; but we are getting down to the last 15% of the roll if that matters.

[image: PLA Globbing Up on the Extruder]

------------------- EDIT With More Information ---------------

Switched out the PLA and my printer is printing great again! Per the suggestion from someone, I'm currently baking the old PLA and will report back on the results!

Comment: Does it happen with another roll? If not, wet filament is a likely culprit. Being wet makes it print like your hotend is 20-30 degrees cooler, which would give poor flow and poor adhesion, leading to stray material all over the place happy to get stuck to the nozzle the next time the nozzle passes over it.

Comment: Just ordered another roll to see. Currently, its the only roll I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think the filament has absorbed too much moisture. You can bake it and then try again.

I bake 2 hours at 50 degrees which works ok for me. But the first time I did this some of the roll tried to fuse together and the innermost 1/4 was wasted. So I've found that it's best to loosen the filament on the roll before baking if it's not that much. If it's a full roll I actually unwind it onto an empty spool and roll it loosely.

Comment: Nice answer. I've found that some manufacturers wind their rolls with too much tension, which drives the filament to deform and try to fuse when dried... which is rather infuriating. Better ones don't seem to have this problem.

Comment: Best of luck with the experiment.

Comment: BTW, I know its been awhile later; but looping back I took the roll of filament and put it in my wife's dehydrator for 2-3 hours. It worked great after that.

Comment: @Doug nice outcome, thanks for letting us know